# Multiple conditions in Flow Designer validation

Tags: validation, visual-workflow

I'm trying to add validation to a number field in a flow screen.

```
    OR(
    ({!Renewal_Terms_0} = {!Renew_at_List_Price}),
    ({!Renewal_Terms_0} = {!Renew_at_Capped_Increase} && {!X1st_Year0} < 100),
    ({!Renewal_Terms_0} = {!Renew_at_Fixed_Price} && {!X1st_Year0} > 100)
    )
```

I've also tried:

```
    ({!Renewal_Terms_0} = {!Renew_at_List_Price})
    ||
    ({!Renewal_Terms_0} = {!Renew_at_Capped_Increase} && {!X1st_Year0} < 100)
    ||
    ({!Renewal_Terms_0} = {!Renew_at_Fixed_Price} && {!X1st_Year0} > 100)
```

I've tried the individual lines as validation on their own and they work as expected but when put together nothing happens.
`Renewal_Terms_0` is a choice picklist.